# Evaluating the alternating hyperbolic series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k \sinh (\pi k)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, theta-functions

You can evaluate the alternating hyperbolic series $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k^{2n-1} \sinh (\pi k)}$$ for any positive even value of $n$ by integrating the function  $$\frac{\pi \csc (\pi z)}{z^{2n-1} \sinh (\pi z)}$$ around a square contour that avoids the poles on both the real and imaginary axes.

For example, $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k^{3} \sinh (\pi k)} = - \frac{\pi^3}{360} $$ and $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k^{7} \sinh (\pi k)} = - \frac{13 \pi^7}{453,600}. $$

However, if you try that same thing for a positive odd value of $n$,  the residues inside of the contour cancel each other, and you're left with the trivial equation $0=0$.

So what would be a way to show that

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k \sinh (\pi k)} = \frac{\pi}{12} - \frac{\log 2}{2} \,  ?$$

Furthermore, do closed form expressions for $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k^{5} \sinh (\pi k)} $, $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k^{9} \sinh (\pi k)} $, etc. exist?

---

It seems like the best way to evaluate the case $n=1$ is to express the series in terms of the [lattice sum](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LatticeSum.html) $$\sum_{i=-\infty}^{\infty} \sum_{j=-\infty}^{\infty}   \frac{(-1)^{i+j}}{i^{2}+j^{2}}, \quad (i,j) \ne (0,0), $$ as explained [here](https://people.math.carleton.ca/%7Ewilliams/papers/pdf/228.pdf), and then use the [Lambert series](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertSeries.html) $$\theta_{4}^{2}(0,q) =  1 + 4 \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{m}q^{m}}{1+q^{2m}} $$ to evaluate the lattice sum (as explained [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/252110251_A_note_on_lattice_sums_in_two_dimensions)).

Comment: This sum is related to Ramanujan's class invariants. $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n \sinh(\pi b n)}=\frac{\pi b}{12}-\log(\sqrt{2} G_{b^2}^2)$$.  See [here](http://people.math.carleton.ca/~williams/papers/pdf/228.pdf) for the complete proof.

Comment: Thanks for the link.

Comment: Exoanding as a series in $e^{-\pi n}$ your series has an expression in term of $\log\Delta(i/2),\log\Delta(i),\log\Delta(2i)$

Comment: A related question can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2602500).

Comment: [Also related.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1316061)

Comment: Here is another variant of the sum: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2469841/72031