# Expressing $\sum \sum_{i,j \in[-n,n], (i,j)\ne (0,0)} \frac{(-1)^{j+k}}{\sqrt{j^2+k^2}}$ in a different way

Tags: summation

I try to separate the following double sum

$$S=\sum_{i,j \in[-n,n], (i,j)\ne (0,0)} f_{ij}$$

where

$$f_{ij}=\frac{(-1)^{j+k}}{\sqrt{j^2+k^2}}$$

$$S=\sum _{k=1}^n \sum _{j=1}^n (f(-k,-j)+f(-k,j)+f(k,-j)+f(k,j))$$

but I do not know why it does not work for several value of integers.

Could you help to get a formula for n dimensional sum

Thanks

Comment: I try sum lattice sums and  I need a general n dimension formula ,it is a way of begining ,Thanks @Jean Marie

Comment: Your title is misleading: as I understand, you look for a closed-form formula...

Comment: Yes pleases , in dimension two or three is will be ok

Comment: What do you mean by "change of indices", by "separate" ? Explain with detailed sentences what you want to do.

Comment: In order to attract more people, I have changed your expressions which had a hard-to-read "Wolfram Alpha"/Mathematica syntax into their usual mathematics syntax.

Comment: Your last expression is not the right one because you exclude for example indices (k=1,j=0) which should be included.

Comment: I think there is an issue about vocabulary: what do you mean when you say "$n$ dimensional sum" ? With terms of the form $\dfrac{(-1)^{a+b+...+n}}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+...+n^2}}$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a numerical simulation giving the values of $S$ from $n=1$ to $n=100$.

A convergent behavior takes place with oscillations around a limit $\approx 1.164$.

[image]

but I am unable to find its exact value.

Nevertheless, this kind of sum has been studied: it is $b_2(1)$ with $b_2(s)$ given by formula (3), Problem n° 3 in this interesting [document]
(https://www.davidhbailey.com//dhbpapers/tenproblems.pdf)

See as well [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1679969p10708784).

Both documents mention this formula:

$$b_2(s)=-4\beta(s)\zeta(s)$$

which unfortunately is valid only for $s>1$.

Somewhat related: [Infinite sum involving number of solutions to $k=i^2+j^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1316061)

Comment: thanks @Jean Marie for the try maybe  I express myself really bad what  I want  , I can calculation de numerical result but this is not the question, the double sum goes fron - Infinity t o infnity I  need it is to get a representation of this sum for 0 to infnity for other reasons

Comment: Could you say what you call "to get a representation" ? Is it a "closed-form formula" (see what this expression mean) ? And what do you mean about "n" dimensional sum in your question ?

Comment: in Math languaje $$\sum _{k=-n}^n \sum _{j=-n}^n \to \sum _{k=1}^n \sum _{j=1}^n$$

Comment: You had asked a question previously a question on Madelung constant : you should link your questions in order to help people to help you.